# ToolTip For Unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list with images on the left of the list and their description on the right. My boss wants for every item in the list to give a tooltip every time the user hovers each item on the list. I tried using some jQuery plugins online however, it only allowed one tooltip for the whole item not for each item. I need help on this. A good example will be helpful.

Comment: As you said, a good example will be helpful. What have you tried? It should be possible adding a tooltip for each item.

Answer (score 27):

Will simply adding a `title` attribute to each list element be sufficient?

```
<li title="tooltip goes here">Blah blah blah</li>
```

Comment: This is a good idea. If the user doesn't have javascript, they'll see the tooltip. If you want to fancy it up, most jquery tooltip plugins can be configured to use the title element.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could do, which could probably be trimmed for conciseness, but it works well:

```
var pageX, pageY;

$(document).mousemove(
    function(e){
        pageX = e.pageX;
        pageY = e.pageY;
    });

$('#tooltipped li[title]').hover(
    function(){
        var tip = $('<div />')
            .addClass('tooltip')
            .text($(this).attr('title'))
            .css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'top' : pageY,
                'left' : pageX
            });
        $(tip).appendTo($(this));
        $(this).mousemove(
            function(){
                $('.tooltip').css(
                    {
                        'top' : pageY,
                        'left' : pageX
                    });
            });
    },
    function(){
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsA3X/).

Edited to remove the `title` attributes (in order to prevent a second pop-up alongside the jQuery tooltip):

```
var pageX, pageY;

$(document).mousemove(
    function(e){
        pageX = e.pageX;
        pageY = e.pageY;
    });

$('#tooltipped li[title]')
    .each(
        function(){
            $(this).attr('data-tooltip',$(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
        })
    .hover(
    function(){
        var tip = $('<div />')
            .addClass('tooltip')
            .text($(this).attr('data-tooltip'))
            .css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'top' : pageY,
                'left' : pageX
            });
        $(tip).appendTo($(this));
        $(this).mousemove(
            function(){
                $('.tooltip').css(
                    {
                        'top' : pageY,
                        'left' : pageX
                    });
            });
    },
    function(){
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VsA3X/1/).

Comment: Nice work, but you need to remove the `title` attribute from each element as you go. I'm seeing both your tooltip and the `title` tooltip overlapping it.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the second code block that's why I updated the demo. (The original was, I guess, just a proof of concept...).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I want tooltips i use the following plugin

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

There are lots of examples on there
For a list :

html :

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li title="tooltip text">Something here</li>
</ul>
```

script :

```
$('#mylist li").tooltip();
```

If the user doesn't have javascript enabled they will see the normal title tooltip