# On hover of li display tooltip javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to display tooltip on hover of li tag. The tooltip contains name and description provided 
from an array. myArray contains name and description that should be displayed in the tooltip on 
mouse hover.How should i proceed with it?

```js
var myArray = {
  rose: "Roses are red",
  lily: "Lilies are white"
};
```

```html
<ul class="selection">
  <li>Roses</li><br><br><br>
  <li>Lilies</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take following approach to achieve this:

- Fetch all necessary `li`s.
- Loop  over these `li`s to set `title` so that the value is displayed as tooltip.

**Note:** In below example, I have added `data-key` so that I can map key of `myArray` to associated `li`. If you have proper keys mapped to li's text or other attribute, use that.

```js
var myArray = {
  rose: "Roses are red",
  lily: "Lilies are white"
};

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
  li.title = myArray[ li.getAttribute('data-key') ]
})
```

```html
<ul class="selection">
  <li data-key='rose'>Roses</li><br><br><br>
  <li data-key='lily'>Lilies</li>
</ul>
```

#### References:

- [ToolTip For Unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996163/tooltip-for-unordered-list)
- [MDN - Node.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- [MDN - Element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: I just want to know one more thing. How can i add html content in the tooltip? Like {rose: "<h1>Roses are red</h1>"}. If i put this in myArray it just displays it like a text and not a heading.

Comment: You cannot do that. Tooltip is a string property. If you want a styled component in tooltip, look into popovers or library's component like: [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/)